# Raw Strings in Code::Blocks?

Tags: c++, rawstring

I am reading a directory from a file, for example I loaded this `"Main\Characters\Player.xxx"`, so I want to create the folders Main and Characters. I tried using this method (after removing Player.xxx from the string)":

```
string syntax = "md "+path;
system(syntax.c_str());
```

However, '\' is counted as an escape and not a backslash, the optimal solution is to replace every '\' with a '\' but that would increase my tool from O(n) to O(2n) given that it needs 30 seconds to fully finish each part. Is there a way to use Raw strings in Code::Blocks? as `R"(\w\\\w)";` didn't do the job for me. *(R is not declared in this scope)*.

Any other solution that doesn't revolve around Raw strings is also welcome.

Comment: Just to be clear, O(n) and O(2n) are the same.

Comment: And O(1) can take a billion years or more.

Comment: @GManNickG I know that they're the same, but think of it logically.

Comment: I know what you mean, but just say "then I have to iterate twice", which is simpler and clearer. :) Anyway, Code::Blocks is an IDE, not a language. C++11 supports raw strings, and if you're getting errors using them then you just need to enable C++11 support in your compiler.

Comment: @GManNickG I guess I'll do what you say then.

Comment: The amount of time taken to insert the `'\\'` is likely dwarfed by the cost of the `system` call and the making of the directory. Don't expect a noticeable performance improvement from this unless something has gone seriously wrong.

Comment: @user4581301 So relatively it's fast. Anyways I optimized it as much as possible (Reading the entire file byte by byte and automatically strong a string into a a variable string, and each '\' adds another one after it. So I kept it O(n). 

Thanks to everyone who contributed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer 1 - Upgrade to another Compiler.
Answer 2 - Simply replace every \ with \

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings>Compiler, then check the box next to where it says have g++ follow the C++11 ISO C++ language standard.

This will allow you to use the features introduced by the 2011 standard, which includes the R prefix.